# Delphi OpenGL resize

Tags: delphi, opengl

I've a question about using OpenGL from Delphi.
My intention is to draw a grid of n rows and n columns in a form. i want the cells in the grid to be square like this image:

[image]

This is the code I use to create this grid:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, Winapi.OpenGL, System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    PopupMenu: TPopupMenu;
    mnuDrawGrid: TMenuItem;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mnuDrawGridClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    glDC: HDC;
    oldW: Integer;
    oldH: Integer;
    glContext: HGLRC;
    errorCode: GLenum;
    openGLReady: Boolean;
    procedure DisegnaLinea(const aX1, aY1, aX2, aY2: Double; aSpessore,
      aOffSet: Integer);
    procedure DisegnaTabellone(const aNumRighe, aNumColonne: SmallInt);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ Gestione form -------------------------------------------------------------- }

// OpenGL initialization
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  pfd: TPixelFormatDescriptor;
  formatIndex: Integer;
begin
  FillChar(pfd, SizeOf(pfd), 0);
  with pfd do
  begin
    nSize := SizeOf(pfd);
    nVersion := 1;
    dwFlags := PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
    iPixelType := PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    cColorBits := 24;
    cDepthBits := 32;
    iLayerType := PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
  end;
  glDC := GetDC(Handle);
  formatIndex := ChoosePixelFormat(glDC, @pfd);
  if formatIndex = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Choose pixel format failed ' + IntToStr(GetLastError));
  if not SetPixelFormat(glDC, formatIndex, @pfd) then
    raise Exception.Create('Set pixel forma failed ' + IntToStr(GetLastError));
  glContext := wglCreateContext(glDC);
  if not glContext = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Create context failed ' + IntToStr(GetLastError));
  if not wglMakeCurrent(glDC, glContext) then
    raise Exception.Create('Make current failsed ' + IntToStr(GetLastError));

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity;
  glOrtho(0.0, ClientWidth, 0.0, ClientHeight, 0.0, 1.0);

  oldW := ClientWidth;
  oldH := ClientHeight;

  openGLReady := True;
end;

// OpenGL destruction
procedure TfrmMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  wglMakeCurrent(Canvas.Handle, 0);
  wglDeleteContext(glContext);
end;

// Form resize
procedure TfrmMain.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not openGLReady then
    exit;
  glViewport(0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
  errorCode := glGetError;
  if errorCode <> GL_NO_ERROR then
    raise Exception.Create('Form resize: ' + gluErrorString(errorCode));
  if (ClientWidth <> oldW) and (ClientHeight <> oldH) then
    DisegnaTabellone(10, 10);
  oldW := ClientWidth;
  oldH := ClientHeight;
end;


{ Gestione menu -------------------------------------------------------------- }

// Menu option grid drawing
procedure TfrmMain.mnuDrawGridClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DisegnaTabellone(10, 10);
end;



{ OpenGL --------------------------------------------------------------------- }

// Draw a line at aX1, aY1 to aX2, aY2 coordinates
procedure TfrmMain.DisegnaLinea(const aX1, aY1, aX2, aY2: Double; aSpessore,
  aOffSet: Integer);
begin
  glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
  glLineWidth(aSpessore);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(aX1, aY1);
    glVertex2f(aX2, aY2);
  glEnd;
end;

// Grid design
procedure TfrmMain.DisegnaTabellone(const aNumRighe, aNumColonne: SmallInt);
const
  vOffSet = 20;
var
  idx: SmallInt;
  pX: Double;
  pY: Double;
  incX: Double;
  incY: Double;
  hPos: Double;
  hWidth: Double;
  widthArea: Integer;
  heightArea: Integer;
  aspectRatio: Double;
begin
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

  widthArea := ClientWidth;
  heightArea := ClientHeight;
  aspectRatio := widthArea / heightArea;

  pY := vOffSet / 2;
  incY := (heightArea - vOffSet) / aNumRighe;

  pX := (widthArea - aNumColonne * incY) / 2;
  hPos := pX;
  hWidth := hPos + aNumColonne * incY;
  incX := incY;

  // Draw vertical lines
  for idx := 0 to aNumColonne do begin
    DisegnaLinea(pX, vOffSet / 2, pX, heightArea - vOffSet / 2, 3, 0);
    pX := pX + incX;
  end;

   // Draw horizontal lines
  for idx := 0 to aNumRighe do begin
    DisegnaLinea(hPos, pY, hWidth, pY, 3, 0);
    pY := pY + incY;
  end;

  glFlush;
end;

end.
```

I initialize the pixel format description in the FormCreate event and Ive created a routine called by a popup menu in order to draw the grid. In this routine I make same calculation because I want the grid cells to be square as I said. So I take the height of the form (ClientHeight) and I divide it for the number of rows I need: in this case 10 plus i'ce a little offset in order to have a margin on the top and bottom of the form. Then I calculate the width of the grid for a perfet square. It works well but the problem come when I resize the form. 
My intension is to draw a new grid smaller or larger according to the form dimensions, but this is only my intention because the grid does'nt mantein the correct aspet ratio and is drawn in a bad manner as ou can see in the following picure:

[image]

I can't understand where is the error in my code. I'm nwe at OpenGL so can someone help me?

Eros

Comment: I recomend using a debugger to see the extreme values you draw with `DisegnaLinea()`

Answer (score 2):

1. Although you set the new `glViewport()` on resize, you still use the old orthographic projection matrix which is no more relevant.
2. So, all you need is an additional `glOrtho()` before setting a new viewport.
3. OpenGL immediate mode (`glBegin()`, `glEnd()`, `glVertex()`, etc.) had been obsolete for nearly twenty years; you really shouldn`t be using it in 2017.

Comment: Many thanks hidefromkgb, not it work fine. As said I'm a newbie of OpenGL so: what should i use instead of glBegin, glEnd and glVertex? I found them in a old book (1999) but I can't find something newer on the internet

Comment: @Eros, I\`d recommend you [to begin here](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle). Unfortunately, all code is in C++, but as long as it boils down to calling GL functions, it can easily be ported to Delphi.

Comment: There is a very good Delphi version of tutorials that hidefromkgb has cited, they are in this github's repository : https://github.com/neslib/DelphiLearnOpenGL/wiki